# Stop bootstrap from creating anchor tags

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have recently started writing some server side code for our new bootstrap themed administrative site.

In the markup I can not find where/how/why bootstrap is adding random anchor tags to some of the HTML divisions.

Example from chrome developer tools below... these exist nowhere in the markup.

Is there a way to disable this? 
How does it silently create these anchor tags? 
What is the reason behind this?

[image]

Here is the html , it adds a partial view with Razor to render the body, but before that you can see where the anchor from the image above is not written.

```
    <div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content" style="overflow:auto;">
            @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END CONTENT -->
```

Comment: Are you really sure it's Bootstrap and not Razor or some other library?

Comment: I think that you are using some jquery library to scroll your content. Bootstrap doesn't add anchor in this way

Comment: Thank you.. I will keep digging.

Comment: the problem is at `@RenderBody()`... not `bootstrap`...